# Alternative to case statments when changing a lot of numeric controls

Tags: labview

I'm pretty new to LabVIEW, but I do have experience in other programing languages like Python and C++. The code I'm going to ask about works, but there was a lot of manual work involved when putting it together. Basically I read from a text file and change control values based on values in the text file, in this case its 40 values.

I have set it up to pull from a text file and split the string by commas. Then I loop through all the values and set the indicator to read the corresponding value. I had to create 40 separate case statements to achieve this. I'm sure there is a better way of doing this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: LabVIEW code]

Comment: What is this file used for? Is it some configuration file, or simple data file?

Comment: @kosist Yeah, its a configuration file. I have it set up, so the user can save some parameters for a test. That data is stored in a text file which I pull from when the user wants to load in new parameters.

Comment: Your title says you want to change **controls**, but your question text talks about **indicators**. Is it one or the other, or both?

Comment: @nekomatic That was a mistype by me. I've changed it. It should of read controls and not indicators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be done following improvements (additionally to suggested by **sweber**:

1. If file contains just data, without "label - value" format, then you could read it as csv (comma separated values) format, and read actually just 1st row.
2. Currently, you set values based on order. In this case, you could: create reference to all indicators, build them to array in proper order, in For Loop assign values to indicators via property node Value.
   [image: Code snippet]
   Overall, I support **sweber** that if it is some key - value data, then better to use either JSON format, or .ini file format, which support such structure.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some optimization:

It seems your data file contains nothing more than just 40 numbers. You can wire an 1D DBL array to the default input of the string-to-array VI, and you will get just a 1D array out. No need for a 2D array.

Second, there is no need to convert the FOR index value to a string, the CASE accepts integers, too.

Now, about your question: The simplest solution is to display the values as array, just as they come from the string-to-array VI.

But I guess each value has a special meaning, and you would like to display it's name/description somehow. In this case, create a cluster with 40 values, edit their labels as you like, and make sure their order in the cluster is the same as the order of the values in the files. 
Then, wire the 1D array of values to this cluster via an array-to-cluster VI.

If you plan to use the text file to store and load the values, converting the cluster data to JSON and vv. might be something for you, as it transports the labels of the cluster into the file, too. (However, changing labels is an issue, then)

Comment: For some reason with my code if I don't convert the loop iteration to a string I get the error: "Case Structure: Selector values have wrong type". That's why I am converting to a string. Why would this be happening?

Comment: This could happen if you had specified one type of case structure pages selectors (in your case - string type), and then connected to selector input integer type.

Comment: If you just want to read in and display a lot of different values then this is a good answer, but I think the questioner actually wants to set the values of front panel *controls* from the saved configuration.